# VBA Outlook TypeLib.GUID "Object required"

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to run this simple code in Outlook 2013. It's a simple copy/paste from [the Scripting Guys website](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/21/how-can-i-create-a-guid-using-a-script.aspx).

```
Sub testGUID()
 Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
 Wscript.Echo TypeLib.GUID
End Sub
```

Running this code throws an "Object Required" exception. The TypeLib.GUID method doesn't seem to be known.
Runs perfectly well with Excel.
Why ?

BR,
Nico

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a local variable first, for example:

```
Sub testGUID()
 Dim TypeLib as Object
 Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
 Wscript.Echo TypeLib.GUID
End Sub
```

Comment: Try searching the windows registry for the object mentioned in the CreateObject method.

Comment: it is there, and then ?

Comment: It looks like the issue is not related to Outlook. Try to run the code in any other application. Does it work?

Comment: Runs very well with Excel, that's why I'm confused